# Wamp's localhost taking so much time on opening

Tags: windows-7, localhost, wamp, phpmyadmin

I have following configuration for `WAMP` on local machine `Windows 7`.

[image]

When I try to open `localhost` from `WAMP` Notification icon, it's taking so much time (around in minutes). Even `phpmyadmin` is taking so much time.

Any idea that How to resolve this?

Comment: You can find a collection of workarounds in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17163207/165358). It would be useful to try them out and add some comments regarding your (lack of) success into your post.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc. Sure I will go through the Answer you suggested in link.

Comment: I’ve been having a similar problem with my homemade WAMP stack. Mine isn’t quite that slow, but it’s slow enough that using WordPress becomes sufficiently frustrating that I can’t just open a browser window, click a link, then type up an article when I get an idea for one; I end up putting them in text-files for batch-entry later on. In my case, I strongly suspect that the problem is because I am using a FastCGI version of PHP because I was lead to believe that it was *faster*. Go figure. What’s your configuration? Do you get instances of `php-cgi.exe` running or is your PHP an Apache module?

Comment: @Synetech, Yes. PHP as an Apache Module like following entry in httpd.conf file `LoadModule php5_module`

Comment: I’ve read advice about improving performance by changing PHP to load as a Fast-CGI process as well as changing to load as an Apache module. This mutually exclusive advice isn’t particularly useful. Personally, I currently have it running as FCGI, but that means that you cannot set PHP directives in an `.htaccess` file per-directory, so I’m going to change it back to an Apache module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue as well and while looking for a solution, I read several pages with advice on fixing this it. <sup>[(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791862/localhost-rendering-pages-are-very-slow?rq=1), [(2)](http://www.borngeek.com/2011/04/05/mysql-performance-and-localhost-performance/), [(3)](https://serverfault.com/questions/66347/the-localhost-response-very-slow-why), [(4)](http://cubicspot.blogspot.ca/2010/07/fixing-slow-apache-on-localhost-under.html).</sup>

There are several suggestions, but the general consensus seems to be that the two most effective fixes are the following:

- Changing PHP to be run as an Apache module or as a Fast-CGI process (I have seen *both* suggested as being faster)
- Adding a line to the `HOSTS` file to resolve `localhost`: `127.0.0.1 localhost`
- Disable IPv6
- Replace all occurrences of `localhost` in your configuration files (for Apache, MySQL, and PHP) with `127.0.0.1`

I ended up adding a registry entry to disable IPv6, but I have not rebooted yet, and moreover, I had already disabled it through the normal Windows interface settings, so I don’t think it has had any effect yet.

I also replaced `localhost` with `127.0.0.1` in my configuration files which seems to have had the most effect, bringing my WordPress page-loading times down from ~7 seconds down to ~2 seconds.

In addition, I also performed a test whereby I started the `dnscache` service (after replacing my normal, large `hosts` file with a tiny one of course). That seems to have drastically increased *all* browsing performance (which means I now have to find a way to get around the 100%-CPU load that the service creates with a large `hosts` file).

Comment: A am appreciating your answer :)

Comment: Happy to help. Let me know what your results are. If it doesn’t work, then we can try some of the other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem long ago.
And after stumbling upon the internet for hours, i finally figured out that there is some misconfiguration with my firewall settings.
I suggest you to check your firewall/antivirus settings.

Also if you are using a proxy or vpn, try turning it off or adding exception for localhost.